# How can I import a file with common keywords in robot framework?

Tags: testing, robotframework

In a robot framework, I have a test suite like this:

```
test-suite/
  ├── Common.robot
  ├── TestCaseA.robot
  └── TestCaseB.robot
```

The file `Common.robot` defines some keywords which will used by both `TestCaseA.robot` and `TestCaseB.robot`. In other languages `Common.robot` would be called a library, but trying to import it like this

```
*** Settings ***
Library         Commons
```

or like that

```
*** Settings ***
Library         Commons.robot
```

results in an error.

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file '[...]/TestCaseA.robot': Importing test library 'Commons' failed: ImportError: No module named Commons
```

The keyword `Library` seems to work only for low level test libraries. I am sure there has to be another way. How can user-defined libraries be included in robot framework?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If `Common.robot` is a plain text file or tab separated file having robot framework keywords, it should be imported in the `Settings` table. In robot framework, files with shared keywords are called [resource files](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#resource-files).

```
*** Settings ***
Resource      Common.robot
```

However, if it is a python file having shared keywords, it should be resourced as a library as

```
*** Settings ***
Library      Common.py
```

Note that in both cases the full filename has to be specified.

Comment: To add to this, it is possible to call a Resource file from a Resource file if you want to have layered keywords (such as "shared between suites" and "within just this suite") or if you want to merge two sets of keywords (such as "page 1 keywords" and "page 2 keywords" for a test that covers two pages).